# Code Execution From Live USB's

Tags: chroot

For the purposes of education, I am trying to work out how to execute code onto a hard drive that has been mounted onto a Linux live USB.

So far I have downloaded a copy of Ubuntu, and just run the command below to mount the hard drive onto the live USB.

```
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
```

I was under the impression that if I were to chroot onto the drive, then I would be able to execute code directly onto the drive. However, I hit a problem with chroot.

```
sudo chroot /mnt
failed to run command ‘/bin/bash’: No such file or directory
```

Is what I'm ultimately trying to do going to work? If so, how can I fix this chroot problem I'm seeing?

Comment: What do you mean by you're trying to "execute code onto a hard drive"?  And, why do you need to use chroot to accomplish that?  Its failing because when you use chroot, it changes the root of your filesystem to the directory passed and then tries to launch a new shell from there.  You probably don't have a directory at `/mnt/bin`, so its unable to launch the shell.

Comment: I can't be more specific that what I said really. Maybe an example helps. Let's say you have a script does something (anything), maybe just removes a folder from the drive. It it possible that when that script is run from chroot, that the code is executed on that hard drive, and not the live USB? I want to know how to install a program onto the hard drive & not the live USB.

Comment: Is there a specific program you are trying to install on the hard drive?  Code does not run on a hard drive, so your question is a little bit confusing.  Code is run by your processor.  Scripts and programs that running may access different storage locations like your hard drive, but the storage is not involved in the execution, and usually its just a matter of telling the program to use the right storage location, you shouldn't have to use chroot.

Comment: No particular program. I'm interested in the security of machines. So I wondered if it was possible to make some malicious script that installed malware (like a RAT) on the machine so that when it next booted up normally, I could gain remote control of the device.